# Remove empty values from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a question regarding a dictionary in python and empty values.
If I had the following dictionary

```
my_dict={'a':[],
 'b':[1],
 'c':[],
 'd':[]
}
```

How I could remove empty values [] and appending the keys in an empty list?

```
my_dict={
 'b':[1],
}
```

and `empty_list=['a','c','d']`.
With a list I would do as follows (but there are several ways to do the same):

```
my_dict = list(filter(None, my_dict))
```

But I have realised I do not know how to do the same in a dictionary.

Comment: `{k:v for k,v in my_dict.items() if v is not None}`?

Comment: Hi Marcin, it answers partially. I am still not understand how to remove empty values :(

Comment: thanks @yatu. I have not tried it yet. Thanks a lot

Comment: seriously, sometimes it is hard for me to understand the reason why some questions are down voted and some others (with no reproducible data, no attempt of solution, ...) are not :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do two explicit iterations for a clean solution -- first calculate the `empty_list`, then filter down `my_dict`:

```
empty_list = [k for k, v in my_dict.items() if len(v) == 0]
my_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if len(v) != 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension to remove empty values:

```py
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if v}
```

Then you can use set difference to get the removed keys:

```
removed_keys = my_dict.keys() - new_dict.keys()
```